# Working solution for ``watch ps aux | grep foo``

Tags: bash, pipe, ps, watch

`watch ps aux | grep foo` is not working: `` bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}' ``

How can I fix this or is there even a better way?

Comment: Are you *sure* that's where the error is coming from? What does `type watch` say? `type grep`? What is the surrounding context (if any) where you're running this?

Comment: If you've been locked out of your account, please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/reset-password.

Answer (score 33):

The problem is that you are watching the wrong thing

1. `watch ps aux | grep foo`

implies that you want to grep foo in the output of watch - which unfortunately is silent by itself. It is indeed running  `ps aux` every 2 seconds, but not printing anything on stdout.

However , the following

2. `watch 'ps aux | grep foo'`

implies you want to watch if anything matching `foo` is printed by `ps aux` . And that is what you want to do.

Hence you would want to go with Option 2

Comment: huh, this was working yesterday but today I'm only seeing an apparently truncated list of processes, all owned by root.  Running ps aux alone and ps aux | tee -a test.txt both work as expected, but then wrapped by watch as $watch 'ps aux | tee -a test.txt' I only get a short list of processes owned by root. Why, Linux, why?